# Media player does not work in certain podcast list

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Here is my code:

```
            Intent i= getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "PodcastSong (1):"+i.getStringExtra("PodcastSong"));
            m_PodcastSong = i.getStringExtra("PodcastSong"); 
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "m_PodcastSong (1):"+m_PodcastSong);
            btnPodcast_grey.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnOnAir_grey.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnPlayPodcast.setEnabled(false);
            btnPodcast_grey.setEnabled(false);
            ShowProgressDialog Task = new ShowProgressDialog();
            Task.execute();
            ListenNowTimer();

        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "OnCreate-Error:" + t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    }

  public static void RunPlaylist(int intPosition){
        try
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RunPlaylist");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, Integer.toString(intPosition));
            relaxResources_Podcast();
            if (mp_Podcast==null){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Create Media Player (Podcast) - yes");
                mp_Podcast = new MediaPlayer();
            }else{
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Create Media Player (Podcast) - no");
            }
            mState_Podcast=State.Retrieving;
            PodcastList.clear();
            PodcastList = getPlayList();
            SetPodcastLayout();
            SetPodcastPlayLayout();
            playSong(intPosition);  
            blnListenNow=false;
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "RunPlaylist-Error:" + t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    }
  public static void RunListenNow(String strPodcastSong){
        try
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RunListenNow");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, strPodcastSong);
            relaxResources_Podcast();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "after relaxResources_Podcast");
            if (mp_Podcast==null){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Create Media Player (Podcast) - yes");
                mp_Podcast = new MediaPlayer();
            }else{
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Create Media Player (Podcast) - no");
            }
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            //Add song into playlist
            mState_Podcast=State.Retrieving;
            PodcastList.clear();
            PopulateListenNow(strPodcastSong);
            SetPodcastLayout();
            SetPodcastPlayLayout();
            playSong_ListenNow(0);
            blnListenNow=true;
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
            btnPrevious.setEnabled(false);
            btnPlayPodcast.setEnabled(true);
            btnPodcast_grey.setEnabled(true);

        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "RunListenNow-Error:" + t.getMessage(), t);
        }
    }
  private void ListenNowTimer(){
      try{
          //mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          tmrListenNow = new Timer();
          tmrListenNow.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
              public void run() {
                  ListenNowHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
              }
          },10000,10000);
      } catch (Throwable t) {
          Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CheckMediaPlayerStatus-Error:" + t.getMessage(), t); 
      }
  }
    private Handler ListenNowHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        try{
            //mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tmrListenNow.cancel();
            tmrListenNow.purge();
            mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               //Generate list View from ArrayList

            RunListenNow(m_PodcastSong);
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Process_Handler-Error:" + t.getMessage(), t);
            //project_list.progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        }
    };

  public static void PopulateListenNow(String strPodcastSong){
        try
        {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "String Podcast Song :"+strPodcastSong);
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error1 :");
            String[] arrSong = strPodcastSong.split("~");
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error2 :");
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("Podcast_id", arrSong[0]);
            song.put("Title", arrSong[1]);
            song.put("Prog_Name", arrSong[2]);
            song.put("file_name", arrSong[3]);
            song.put("duration", arrSong[4]);
            song.put("Path", arrSong[5]);
            song.put("desc", arrSong[6]);
            song.put("image_url", arrSong[7]);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error1 :");
            PodcastList.add(song);

        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "PopulateListenNow-Error:" + t.getMessage(), t);
        }
  }
```

Here are the errors:

```
08-02 11:51:29.542: E/Player_listen_now(16044): PopulateListenNow-Error:length=7; index=7
08-02 11:51:29.542: E/Player_listen_now(16044): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7
08-02 11:51:29.542: E/Player_listen_now(16044):     at com.m3tech.bfm.Player_listen_now.PopulateListenNow(Player_listen_now.java:563)
08-02 11:51:29.542: E/Player_listen_now(16044):     at com.m3tech.bfm.Player_listen_now.RunListenNow(Player_listen_now.java:466)
08-02 11:51:29.542: E/Player_listen_now(16044):
```

This is the apps such as ipod...the errors come out when i wanna play the podcast after the user click on the play icon...But it wont work for certain files/songs only...i couldn't identify the problem within the code or the database.

Comment: Isn't there a global unhandled exception handler that you could use to log your exceptions? That would be *way* better than catch blocks in every method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`song.put("image_url", arrSong[7]);`

it throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7`

As some songs does not have any images.so as well as it does not include image_url.
So it will be null at this position in your arrSong.

You can use `try/Catch` for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

e.g

```
    try {
                song.put("image_url", arrSong[7]);

        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
                  song.put("image_url","No Image");
        }
```